# "If-element" does not react when calling included template

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am looking to build a simple logic to let user define which templates that should be called upon. The code illustrates a minimized example. The setup is very useful when having many templates, e.g. the output I am building is about 2.600 lines of XHTML code. Then it is very good being able to exclude several templates to focus on only some of the templates.

I have created above setup (previously) successfully having XML as source file and modularized code. I suspect it is my setup with having JSON as source file and the adaption of code that causes the problem.

Below code should allow the user to switch variable "build-with-books" from 0 to 1, and if set to 1, the "if" element should call the included template.

I am sure that there are many "smarter" way of solving my needs. Currently I am just looking to understand why my code does not follow the wanted logics of switching on/off the build of elements.

XSLT fiddle is down so I just paste my code below:

**data:**

```
<data>
{
  "books": {
    "Wonderland": 43
  },
  "beverage": {
    "Falcon": 12
  }
}
</data>
```

**principal.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Block all data that has no user defined template -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Includes -->
  <xsl:include href="books.xsl"/>

  <!-- Module selector -->
  <xsl:variable name="build-with-books">0</xsl:variable>

  <!-- Attribute-sets -->
  <xsl:attribute-set name="books">
    <xsl:attribute name="category">Adventure</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- Main template -->

  <xsl:template match="data">

      <!-- Parse JSON to XML, results in XML map -->
      <xbrli:xbrl>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </xbrli:xbrl>

      <!-- Call template -->    
      <xsl:if test=" $build-with-books = '1' ">
        <xsl:call-template name="books"/>
      </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Supporting module: books.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn"
  expand-text="yes"
>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Create elements  -->

<xsl:template name="books" match="*[@key = 'books']//*[@key and not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="ix:{@key}" use-attribute-sets="books">{.}</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2">
   <ix:Wonderland category="Adventure">43</ix:Wonderland>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

**Expected result if variable "build-with-books" set to 0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2">
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

**Expected result if variable "build-with-books" set to 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2">
   <ix:Wonderland category="Adventure">43</ix:Wonderland>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `match` from the `books` template? I'm guessing that since you're applying templates to all of the result elements from `json-to-xml()` that template is still matching.

Comment: @DanielHaley, if I remove the match from book template, and keep the variable "build-with-books" to zero, the output does not build with element "Wonderland". That is correct behaviour, but if I also change "build-with-book" to 1, the complete output is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start**

Delete this part from principal.xsl: (call-template uses the current context and that is still your match on data)

```
  <!-- Call template -->    
  <xsl:if test=" $build-with-books = '1' ">
    <xsl:call-template name="books"/>
  </xsl:if>
```

And remove the @name attribute from

```
<xsl:template name="books" match="*[@key = 'books']//*[@key and not(*)]">
```

**Option: 1**

Change match template in books.xls to look like this (it will use your global `$build-with-books` directly)

```
  <xsl:template match="*[$build-with-books='1'][@key = 'books']//*[@key and not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="ix:{@key}" use-attribute-sets="books">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Option: 2**

Make use of [xsl:next-match](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-next-match) in your principal.xsl: (it will first use the template with a higher priority where it checkes that global `$build-with-books`)

Add this:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'books']" priority="10">
    <xsl:if test="$build-with-books='1'">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```